# Grouping sum , count and max to be grouped by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, sum, max

The following is my table structure.

[image]

- I want to get the sum of Defects reported for each sprint and each sprintweek and then display the top defect reporter.

**

Desired output

**

[image]

Comment: your data sample is  not coherent explian better using consistent data and clear explanation  .. why you have defectCount = 3 and DefectSprint week = 2 for B defectReporter ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT DefectReporter, COUNT(*) AS DefectCount, DefectSprint, DefectSprintInWeek
FROM {table}
WHERE {condition}
GROUP BY DefectReporter, DefectSprint, DefectSprintInWeek
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: You need to add `ORDER BY DefectCount DESC`